# Reverse words in string - same order - including whitespace

Tags: python, string

I am trying to reverse the letters of each words contained in a given string, keeping the same word order and also keeping the same whitespace.

So `'This  is  an  example!'` should return: `'sihT  si  na  !elpmaxe'` (note two spaces between each word).

The solution I wrote doesn't deal with this whitespace:

```
def reverse_words(str1):
    list1 = str1.split()
    list2 = []
    for e in list1:
        e = e[::-1]
        list2.append(e)
    return ' '.join(list2)
```

Comment: That should be `.split(' ')`, as without an argument consecutive whitespace is grouped into one. Also, don't name your own object `str`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe post an answer

Comment: @jonrsharpe replaced str by str1. So if I do .split('  ') won't it return 2 whitespaces even if the original string only contains 1 space after each word?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Fair point, tried it with your solution below and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do it without regular expressions, note that `str.split` will *group consecutive whitespace* when called without an explicit argument. To avoid that, specifically split on spaces. Note that you can shorten the whole function using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def reverse_words(string): # don't name your own object str
    return ' '.join([word[::-1] for word in 
                     string.split(' ')])
```

Comment: I think simpler one , but `word[::1]` should be `word[::-1]`

Comment: This takes *779 µs* compared to my solution's *1.91 ms* for a string for length 3000. *+1*.

Comment: @ha9u63ar that's really not helpful

Answer (score 7):

If you want to preserve white space then use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'This is an example!'
>>> re.sub(r'\S+', lambda m:m.group(0)[::-1], s)
'sihT si na !elpmaxe'
>>> s = 'This is an    example!'
>>> re.sub(r'\S+', lambda m:m.group(0)[::-1], s)
'sihT si na    !elpmaxe'
```

Comment: how about this `" ".join(w[::-1] for w in re.split("\s",  'This is an  example!'))`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan This one is slight fast, but speed wise Jon's solutions is the best.

Comment: Good decision! Thank you 